# PCB design: power tracks under the ground plane - is the capacitance going to be disturbing?

Tags: pcb-design, capacitance

I'm designing a PCB that currently looks like this:

[image: Circuit board layout]

I stumbled upon an idea of moving the main power section (especially including 3.3uH coil) and the GSM modem (the one with several drills) to the bottom side of the board and leave all other components on the front side so that those 2 types of functionality are separated. The assumption is also that the ground is going to fill all the empty spaces of the both layes (filled zones).

My only concern is: if at one of the PCB's layer I have a ground plane and at the other one the power line (3.8V @ 2.5 A in peaks) doesn't that make a capacitance that may disturb the operation of the circuits?

Comment: Capacitance between power and ground is usually a good thing. Capacitance between power and signals (especially low-voltage analog signals on high-impedance nets) can be a bad thing.

Comment: As a side note: GSM modems are pretty demanding regarding a good power supply design. While transmitting, there can be short bursts up to 1-2A. It requires proper routing and buffering to make it work properly and reduce EMI. Look for application notes from the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, coupled power and ground planes make excellent high frequency capacitors.

No, a small high frequency capacitor between power and ground will not by itself disturb the operation of your circuit. Why would it?

Comment: My concern is related to GPIO lines (like modem's UART) that are in the neighborhood of this coupled ground and power line. I realize that the capacitance is _between_ not _aside_ the ground and power line, however I am a newbie to electronics and would like to be careful.

Comment: Or in other words: it may be a GPIO line of (~2.5V) that is lead just under the ground plane and it is going to be affected by the capacitance, right? By their nature the GPIO lines shall switch their logic states as fast as possible and in this case they will be possibly slowed down by the capacitance. Or I am totally wrong here :)

Comment: A GPIO line will be affected by capacitance between itself and power or ground. It won't be affected by capacitance between power and ground. It could be affected if the current return for the signal needs to cross over between power and ground --- which happens if part of the trace is nearest to power and part is nearest to ground. Whether to worry about this depends on the rise and fall times when the signal switches between 1 and 0.

Comment: @tml: Just to make that clear: Capacitance goes in all directions. Sideways and up/down included. Coupling between two traces on a board is reduced by bringing the traces closer to a reference plane and increasing the trace-to-trace spacing. The capacitance between a trace and it's reference plane is usually less than 25pF and should not affect a standard GPIO line much, unless you have a fairly extreme case.

Comment: @tml: You probably don't need to be concerned about UART and parasitic capacitive coupling as the frequencies are generally VERY low. This is something you worry about in the tenth of MHz range.

Comment: Can we close this now? Or is there something that have not been answered?

Answer (score -1):

You can choose the thinnest tracks possible to reduce the capacitance on data lines with a ground plane.

It is possible to compute the loading and effective Charcteristic Impedance , Zo, which is only important when using a terminator.

Comment: While what you say is true, its not answering the question.